# Deployment failed or Emulator is not start

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using Windows phone 8 sdk and Visual studio 2012
deployment failed because no Windows phone 8 was detected.
Make sure a phone is connected and power is on

Tell me how can I resolve that error.

Comment: Do you have a device connected? Are you trying to deploy to the emulator? If emulator change the debug type to be the emulator and not a device

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you need to make sure that the OS thinks that the device is connected.

I've had this a few times and addressed it with the following:
 - unplug and then reconnect the device
 - Try a different cable
 - You may also see this if you have a very low battery charge

To confirm that the OS thinks the phone is connected, make sure you can see it in Windows Explorer or the Windows Phone [app for desktop] application.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - the phone just stopped connecting. Turn it off completely (hold on power button and then slide down) and turn on again - Windows will notice it and you will see it in Windows Explorer under "Devices and drivers" section.